# Calculating Cosine Integral and Ci(x)

Tags: java, math, numerical-integration, calculus

I have a basic background in Java, so my knowledge of different structures and implementations is limited.

I was wondering how to calculate the Cosine-Integral in Java.

Specifically, I have `f(x) = sin(2pi C*x)/x^2`

The integral of `this = Constant * Ci(2pi Constant * x) - sin(2pi Constant * x)/x`

I want to calculate the integral of `sin(2pi C * x) / x^2` from 0 to 0.5x (or `sin(0)` to `sin(pi)` in the original f(x).  Unfortunately, I don't know how to evaluate the `Ci(x)` part of the function at my current skill level.

I downloaded the Apache Math3 *.jar and imported it in to my BuildPath, then imported the *.analysis.Integration.*, but have no idea how to:

1. Define a function as input to integrate
2. Actually integrate

I could do with a simple example of evaluating the Cosine-Integral, but I would prefer to learn how to do integrals more generally.

Answer (score 0):

[Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_231.htm) show you how to do it.  So does [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/nrcontents.html).  The NR code is licensed, so be careful about using it without paying up.

The series expansion for Ci(x) appears on [this page](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_232.htm) of A&S.

It should be easy enough to program if you can't find it in existing Java math libraries.